# Disable auto grouping on Windows forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I read a question on the subject [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576886/how-to-avoid-windows-forms-radio-button-container-auto-grouping), but the provided answer doesn't fit my case, and like said, "is a bit overkill".
I have a bunch of radio buttons in a table layout panel on a form, and .NET has decided to manage them on its own, unchecking the others when one is checked, and I don't want that.
From what I understood this is due to .NET grouping controls inside of a same container.

How do I disable that ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `AutoCheck` property to false on each `RadioButton` and then handle check/uncheck logic in the `Click` event.

Comment: That was that simple... Ok. Thank you !

Comment: NOTE : "handle check/uncheck logic in the Click event" means that you need to manually update the display and the check state of the radio button.